# SSRS - Preview Report opening PreviewProcessingService.exe in command prompt

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SQL Server Reporting service. When i click on preview to verify the report, it is opening one command prompt window "PreviewProcessingService.exe". When i am closing this windows i am not able to generate any report. Once i restart the VS and click on the preview tab it is again opening this window.

[image]

I don't why i have to keep this windows open to preview the report. I don't want this windows open. Is there any configuration change to make it work without keeping this windows open? Please provide suggestions.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.